# Ant, can't compile The JBoss Transactions JTA 4.2.3.SP7 from jboss.org

Tags: ant, jboss, transactions

I have downloaded The JBoss Transactions JTA 4.2.3.SP7 from jboss.org http://www.jboss.org/jbosstm/downloads/4-2-3-SP7 , it's a first link. It is written using ant, when I try to run this I have multiple error about lacking files, etc. I have suplemmented all of them, but I get another errors about lacking variables in files, etc. Maybe it wasn't the best way to repair it so I've left it.

So, after downloading this package what should I do to run this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. the solution is to compile it with ant 1.7.x. Greets.